# Troubleshooting VIM markdown-preview on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, vim, plugins, markdown

I keep getting error "E492: Not a command of the editor" when I try to toggle ':MarkdownPreview' on a markdown (*.md) file.

I'm running a MINGW64 terminal (basically Git BASH), on my Windows 11 64bit work laptop.
I have installed node.js as suggested by the official page of  [iamcco /
markdown-preview.nvim](https://github.com/iamcco/markdown-preview.nvim)  plugin and have checked that it appears in Windows' Path environment. I've also installed `yarn` using `npm install --global yarn`.

I'm including below my `~/.vimrc` file for reference.
Everytime I tried something new on .vimrc file I always did

```
:so ~/.vimrc
:VundleInstall
```

on VIM.

Can you please help me find out what am I doing wrong? Is it perhaps the value of `let g:mkdp_browser =`?

I've also noticed that the status bar of VIM signals it's a unix (not .md) document -- I wonder if that's the problem? And if so, how do I fix it?

```bash
set wrap
set relativenumber
set autoindent
set conceallevel=2
set tabstop=4

" Status line right side.
set statusline+=\ ascii:\ %b\ hex:\ 0x%B\ row:\ %l\ col:\ %c\ percent:\ %p%%

" Show the status on the second to last line.
set laststatus=2

" Disable compatibility with vi which can cause unexpected issues.
set nocompatible              

filetype on
filetype plugin on

" Turn syntax highlighting on.
syntax on

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
" call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'godlygeek/tabular'
Plugin 'preservim/vim-markdown'
Plugin 'iamcco/markdown-preview.nvim', { 'do': 'cd app & yarn install' }

" CONFIG preservim/vim-markdown configuration
autocmd FileType markdown let b:sleuth_automatic=0
autocmd FileType markdown set conceallevel=0
autocmd FileType markdown normal zR


"Set header folding level
let g:vim_markdown_folding_level = 1
"Enable TOC window auto-fit
let g:vim_markdown_toc_autofit = 1

" CONFIGN MarkdownPreview 
" set to 1, nvim will open the preview window after entering the markdown buffer
" default: 0
let g:mkdp_auto_start = 1

" set to 1, the nvim will auto close current preview window when change
" from markdown buffer to another buffer
" default: 1
let g:mkdp_auto_close = 1

" set to 1, the vim will refresh markdown when save the buffer or
" leave from insert mode, default 0 is auto refresh markdown as you edit or
" move the cursor
" default: 0
let g:mkdp_refresh_slow = 1

" set to 1, the MarkdownPreview command can be use for all files,
" by default it can be use in markdown file
" default: 0
let g:mkdp_command_for_global = 0

" set to 1, preview server available to others in your network
" by default, the server listens on localhost (127.0.0.1)
" default: 0
let g:mkdp_open_to_the_world = 0

" use custom IP to open preview page
" useful when you work in remote vim and preview on local browser
" more detail see: https://github.com/iamcco/markdown-preview.nvim/pull/9
" default empty
let g:mkdp_open_ip = 'localhost'

" specify browser to open preview page
" for path with space
" valid: `/path/with\ space/xxx`
" invalid: `/path/with\\ space/xxx`
" default: ''
let g:mkdp_browser = 'C:\\Program\ Files\\Mozilla\ Firefox\\firefox.exe'
"let g:mkdp_browser = ''

" set to 1, echo preview page url in command line when open preview page
" default is 0
let g:mkdp_echo_preview_url = 0

" a custom vim function name to open preview page
" this function will receive url as param
" default is empty
let g:mkdp_browserfunc = 'g:open_browser'

" options for markdown render
" mkit: markdown-it options for render
" katex: katex options for math
" uml: markdown-it-plantuml options
" maid: mermaid options
" disable_sync_scroll: if disable sync scroll, default 0
" sync_scroll_type: 'middle', 'top' or 'relative', default value is 'middle'
"   middle: mean the cursor position alway show at the middle of the preview page
"   top: mean the vim top viewport alway show at the top of the preview page
"   relative: mean the cursor position alway show at the relative positon of the preview page
" hide_yaml_meta: if hide yaml metadata, default is 1
" sequence_diagrams: js-sequence-diagrams options
" content_editable: if enable content editable for preview page, default: v:false
" disable_filename: if disable filename header for preview page, default: 0
let g:mkdp_preview_options = {
    \ 'mkit': {},
    \ 'katex': {},
    \ 'uml': {},
    \ 'maid': {},
    \ 'disable_sync_scroll': 0,
    \ 'sync_scroll_type': 'middle',
    \ 'hide_yaml_meta': 1,
    \ 'sequence_diagrams': {},
    \ 'flowchart_diagrams': {},
    \ 'content_editable': v:false,
    \ 'disable_filename': 0,
    \ 'toc': {}
    \ }

" use a custom markdown style must be absolute path
" like '/Users/username/markdown.css' or expand('~/markdown.css')
let g:mkdp_markdown_css = ''

" use a custom highlight style must absolute path
" like '/Users/username/highlight.css' or expand('~/highlight.css')
let g:mkdp_highlight_css = ''

" use a custom port to start server or empty for random
let g:mkdp_port = '3000'

" preview page title
" ${name} will be replace with the file name
let g:mkdp_page_title = '${name}'

" recognized filetypes
" these filetypes will have MarkdownPreview... commands
let g:mkdp_filetypes = ['markdown']

" set default theme (dark or light)
" By default the theme is define according to the preferences of the system
let g:mkdp_theme = 'dark'
```

Comment: Use the [issue tracker](https://github.com/iamcco/markdown-preview.nvim/issues).

Answer (score 0):

I started using gVIM instead of the limited version of VIM that gets bundled in with Git BASH. I also switched over to `vim-plug` as the package manager and cleaned up and modified the `~/.vimrc` file to look like this:

```
set wrap
set relativenumber
set autoindent
set conceallevel=2
set tabstop=4


" Status line right side.
set statusline+=\ ascii:\ %b\ hex:\ 0x%B\ row:\ %l\ col:\ %c\ percent:\ %p%%

" Show the status on the second to last line.
set laststatus=2

" Disable compatibility with vi which can cause unexpected issues.
set nocompatible              

" recognize filetype and load corrisponding plugins
filetype on
filetype plugin on

" highlight cursor line and column
set cursorline
set cursorcolumn

"Turn syntax highlighting on.
syntax on

"Customize gui font
set guifont=Consolas:h10:cDEFAULT

"Customize colorscheme
colorscheme desert

" Insert list of plugins between 'begin' and 'end' 
call plug#begin()

" Plugin to preview md files side by side
" If you have nodejs and yarn
Plug 'iamcco/markdown-preview.nvim', { 'do': 'cd app && yarn install' }
call plug#end()
```

So now typing `:MarkdownPreview` works! It opens up a tab in the browser and I'm able to see the *formatted version* of an `.md` file.